# Set of elements where two maps are equal are closed when co-domain is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

So I just completely flunked my latest assignment and I have to ask someone how to solve the following problem.

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces with $Y$ Hausdorff, and let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous maps. Prove that the set $\{x\in X\vert f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$

What I tried to do was look at each individual singleton $y$ in $Y$ where they would be equal and send it back to $X$ with one of the maps so that I knew it would be closed, but I messed up.

[EDIT]
Could I have considered the map $f-g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [EDIT]
> Could I have considered the map $f-g$?

No, you can't. Since "$-$" is meaningless for arbitrary topological spaces $X,Y$.

You can show this, by showing that the complement is open. Let $A=\{x\in X\ |\ f(x)\neq g(x)\}$. Consider $x\in A$, i.e. $f(x)\neq g(x)$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff then there are open, disjoint subset $U,V\subseteq Y$ such that $f(x)\in U$ and $g(x)\in V$. Let $U'=f^{-1}(U)$ and $V'=g^{-1}(V)$, both are open by continuity. Finally let $W=U'\cap V'$, which is open as well. You can easily check that if $z\in W$ then $f(z)\neq g(z)$. Also $x\in W$. So $W$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ fully contained in $A$ and thus by the arbitrary choice of $x$ we have that $A$ is open. And thus its complement is closed.